# Questions Regarding Hosting a dynamic website on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So i have developed a dynamic website using Eclipse.
I have set up an instance of Amazon EC2 , i have installed Apache Tomcat 7 and MYSQL on it. Using the Apache Tomcat menue by going to publicDns:8080 i have deployed the war file as well. 
The project name is sms.
It works perfectly fine when i visit the site using publicDNS:8080/sms
Now i have created an elastic Ip address and associated it with the instance
I have also pointed my domain to the Ip Address
Now i want that when ever i visit this address it should take me to the index of my deployed website.

Right now i am working with the Ip Address since my domain is still configuring
so what i want is when i visit my Ip Address it should take me to the index of the website
instead what i have to do now is

IpAddress:8080/sms

going to IpAddress alone shows me Unable to Connect Error

How do i configure my EC2 Instance so going to the IpAddress would take me directly to the index

Comment: You will likely need to set up nginx or apache as a proxy to tomcat to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is how i solved the problem
First i renamed by war to ROOT.war , then i deployed it using the normal method from the Manager section of apache home (domainName:8080/manager). Then using putty i connected to my amazon EC2 cloud and navigated to the apache folder, and changed the default port from 8080 to 80.
So now going to the domain name takes me to mywebsite